# If $xy=\pi z$ and we define $f(z)=\pi z$, then is it correct to say that $f(z)$ depends on $z$ alone, not on $x$ and $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Wording confusion on dependent variables

> Consider the surface $$xy = \pi z$$
> suppose I define $f(z) = \pi z$ and rewrite
> $$xy = f(z)$$
>
> - Is it correct to say $f(z)$ is a function of $z$ alone?
> - Is it correct to say $f(z)$ doesn't depend on $x, y$ ? (If yes, how do you justify $f(z) = xy$ ?)

Answer (score 1):

By defining $xy=\pi z$, saying that $f(z)=\pi z$ depends on $z$ alone is the same as saying that $f(z)$ depends on $x$ and $y$, because let's say
$$f(z)=xy$$
In this form, you can't take input and output from a function, because they're different variables and you'll get back to the equation $xy=\pi z \iff z=\frac{xy}{\pi}$, and get
$$f\left(\frac{xy}{\pi}\right)=xy$$
and so $x \mapsto \pi x$ gives
$$f(xy)=\pi x y$$
and now $f$ takes the real number $xy$ and outputs $\pi x y$, regardless of what $x$ and $y$ **individually** are, so if you take $y\ne0$ (because $f(0)=0$ so it's not a problem) you can say $x \mapsto x/y$ and thus
$$f(x)=\pi x$$

so it's not really a mind teaser to say that it depends on both $x$ and $y$. It does only depend on the value of one of them $x$ or $y$, because whenever you place a value on $x$ or $y$, if it is zero, then $f(0)=0$, if it's not, assume WLOG that you placed a value of $y \ne 0$ and then $x \mapsto x/y$ makes $f$ depend on $x$ only.

Because of the specific restriction placed by your definitions of $xy, f(z), z$, the function $f$ is defined to take only one input and gives one output depending on that one input (namely $f(h)=\pi h$ whatever $h$ is in the set of real numbers); it doesn't satisfy to say it **depends** on **both** $x$ and $y$.